# Gaining The Sevenfold Enchantment

Tags: low-fantasy

This question is a follow-up to [Just How Dangerous Would a Plopup Be?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/196760/just-how-dangerous-would-a-plopup-be) and concerns gaining its enchantment.

You see, when any monster dies, its magical essence is released, enchanting items inside it or around its person (especially the weapon that killed it, mind you), as well as the slayer or anyone alive inside of it at the time of death. (For more on the latter, AKA surviving victims, please see this [link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195379/unconventional-rebirth-is-it-checked).)

The Plopup's death effect (read: enchantment), Sevenfold, is especially valuable. An item with this enchantment will be seven times stronger (and more durable), while striking seven times faster and seven times harder. More specifically, Sevenfold armor will be seven times better at negating force (AKA absorbing force without breaking or transferring it to the wearer) and seven times harder, while a Sevenfold sword will not only strike seven times faster and seven times harder, but will be seven times harder and sharper.

On a human being, the Sevenfold enchantment makes one seven times faster, smarter, stronger, and more durable, as well as greatly enhancing their looks, skill level (for all held skills), and any enchantments they hold. As if that wasn't enough, someone with the Sevenfold enchantment is practically immune to poison and disease while having an intense healing factor, allowing them to survive losing limbs or having large chunks of their body hacked off (like an axolotl, but faster-in terms of days or weeks-, magically fueled, and a bit stronger as well).

This of course makes the Sevenfold enchantment very valuable, but getting it is very difficult. In order for a person to gain a monster's enchantment, they have to kill it with their natural weaponry (read: their body), not a weapon like a sword or even a well-timed falling boulder or be alive inside it when it is killed.

The first is almost impossible (I'm not joking, and I would strongly recommend you click on the link above and seeing exactly what a Plopup is capable of), but the second, while guaranteed to be dangerous, is much easier to accomplish, because Plopup have an unnatural penchant for eating scantily clad attractive women.

My question, therefore, is: **What Is The Best Way To Gain The Sevenfold Enchantment?**

**Specifications:**

1. I'm looking for methods that will work either for a monster slayer or a cunning maiden, NOT one or the other. By "Best," I mean safest, most efficient, and easiest to accomplish. It should be feasible for people in Europe during the medieval era, which falls between the fall of the Western Roman Empire and the Renaissance. The less magic involved the better since this is low-fantasy.

Comment: Your last sentence is in open contradiction with everything you said before.

Comment: @Rekesoft: sorry, I didn't mean to be contradictory. I will correct that as soon as I come up with something else to put there. My meaning is simple; for the sake of answering the question, it must not require knowledge of my world one does not have, therefore less magic must be involved.

Comment: It was sort of a joke, don't worry. Your question is fine. I was just pointing that "low-magic" and magic giant monsters who grant superpowers doesn't seem to mix well in my mind. :D

Comment: @Rekesoft: understandable. Those two really don't fit well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Barrels of ale**

99 barrels of ale on the cart
99 barrels of ale on the cart
Take one off
Throw it on a Plopup
98 barrels of ale on the cart

This could be the famous song in your universe. Songs can have many truths and lessons in them, and this can be one.

Plopups seem to be doubly vulnerable vulnerable to alcohol. It intoxicates them, modifying their behaviour. It is also a great way to make something flamable. Although mostly the vapor will burn, the heat can still scorch the skin in a short time if my experience in my youth is any indication. Longer times can definitely be very dangerous.

The economics and technology behind it are also interesting. You'll have to have a medieval period where they know how to fortify alcoholic drinks. A beer doesn't really catch fire, whereas vodka will.

So what will you do when you hunt these things? Take a barrel of fortified ale or other strong but cheap drink. When the encounter starts, you wait on the cart with a few barrels you can tip over to any side. Possibly you make the ground around the cart wet with the alcohol beforehand. When the Plopup is close enough you thow the barrel over it, both starting the intoxication as well as making it flammable. Throw some fire or molotov cocktail and watch it burn.

If it is smart enough to understand the trap, a bunch of molotov cocktails are good anyway. Interestingly is you dissolve some rubber in oil (mostly more modern gas, but might work with lamp oils) the liquid is more 'sticky'.

The rules aren't exactly clear to me, but hopefully the fire or barrel won't be imbued or the attacker can hopefully get close enough to receive it. If not, it is a dangerous but possibly rewarding thing to jump onto the creature and try slashing it, maybe even with hands drenched in lit alcohol, for the finishing blow.

A maiden in a bikini (read the backstory of Plopup) with a basket of molotov cocktails and a lighter might be able to do it. Although more sophisticated traps are recommended. It seems dangerous at all times, although you can kite it with firebombs pretty effectively if done right.

Comment: Valid answer, alcohol is one of a Plopup's greatest weaknesses. As for reading the backstory, I'm the one who made them up, so your advice there is appreciated but unnecessary. The only problem here would be that the Plopup's remains would need to be consumed by the slayer in order to gain the Sevenfold enchantment.

Comment: @Alendyias The backstory reading was for other people :). I didn't read it needs to be consumed in your text. Seemed to be only to kill them. A ditch effort to save the answer, you might be able to eat the Plopup as it'll get trapped in it's own burned husk. You can get some of the innards but by bit and keep burning the rest before it gets out.

Comment: good point, killing a Plopup should give you the enchantment. However, on answers to previous, similar questions I ruled that the enchantment would go into the fire and subsequent ashes. Also, Plopup are like rubber; a burned-up one would be like taffy taken out of a freezer, edible but not exactly appetizing.

Comment: Oh, and you did save your answer. I've thought about it, and if part of you is inside the alcohol, it should grant you the Enchantment. If I remember right, there's an alcoholic beverage called Bloody Mary; add in some blood and it would be a highly ironic addition to your question.

Answer (score 4):

**Domesticated Plopup are docile and can be killed before they become too unwieldy**

The first few Plopups you'll have to catch with swords and weapons, so no sevenfold magic there.  Once you've captured a few, put them together and let them breed.

You now have a reasonably safe, controlled way to get new Plopups that are smaller and safer to handle than full grown ones.  Make sure the new Plopups see humans as friends, and it'll be much easier to kill one when the time comes.

Comment: Very good answer, it reminds me of the experiment that created domesticated silver foxes. However, I'm not sure Plopup (as natural monsters that _want_ to eat people) can see people as friends. Hmmm....much to consider here.....

Comment: "as natural monsters that want to eat people" i mean, people call cats domesticated and my cat tries to eat me every once in a while, usually when im late to feed her

Comment: @Alendyias - "as natural monsters that want to eat people" -> Large domesticated cats (think Tigers) eat people in the wild, but can be trained and domesticated if they are raised by humans from cubs.

Comment: @Topcode: are you joking or serious? I can't tell.

Comment: sevensevens, valid point, there should be nothing stopping someone from domesticating Plopup then. That could be a terrifying asset....

Comment: @Alendyias joking, mainly. My cat does nibble at me sometimes (mainly when i interrupt her doing something with a few pets), but nowhere near enough to be considered eating me, i hope you didn't think i meant my cat taking actual bites out of me, i dont have a lion or something. (:

Comment: @Topcode: no I didn't think your cat was literally eating you, I was just curious.

Answer (score 2):

What about a market for sedating and capturing Plopups to then be held in a cage where they can easily be slain by a human's bare hands for a cost?

I could see a business of talented trappers using this enchantment for profit. Presumably, all of the trappers would also have this enchantment (They would want the enchantment for themselves before selling the sedated Plopups to other people) making them super-human as you pointed out.

You can tailor how challenging Plopups are to capture based on how rare you want the enchantment to be. Maybe they are learning that they are being systematically trapped, and learn other techniques as well to escape the traps.

Comment: I thought I made this relatively clear, perhaps I should have added more information, but Plopup are tough, flexible, and relatively amorphous creatures, seven times more intelligent than an octopus (intelligence rivaling or exceeding that of a human).

Comment: @Alendyias I don't see how any of that makes them impossible to capture. Being tough, flexible and amorphous doesn't help when you have tranquillizer pumping through your body. Also, I bet if you took an octopus and gave it x7 intelligence it wouldn't even come close to humans - do you have a source for that? I'm interested. 
Obviously, you are not keen on the idea, just thought I would throw it out there. Cool world though from what I've read!

Comment: Thank you. I do like your answer, I'm not quite sure how feasible it is though. That being said, I will strongly consider your points.

Answer (score 2):

### (near) naked mud wrestling

In your other questions you list a few pertinent details about Plopups' physiology and psychology:

1. Plopups *"avoid alcohol because it makes them act like idiots"* → they can be poisoned, specifically inebriated
2. Plopups' main attacks involve blunt force, they do not generally use tools
3. Plops can grow by digesting "dirt, dust, slime and grime", which they presumably ingest through their surface → they can ingest substances by contact
4. They display very anthropomorphic tendencies including obsession, irrational anger and classic, inefficient [evil overlord](http://www.eviloverlord.com/lists/overlord.html) behaviours.

I propose that the Plopups have a disproportionate sensitivity to alcohol, which they can absorb through skin contact.  Humans barely absorb alcohol through their skin, so a monster slayer/cunning maiden can slather themselves with an alcohol-rich gel and then ensure... extensive... skin contact with the Plopup, which will become progressively less self-controlled, but no less physically powerful.  Initial contact will need to take advantage of the Plopup's psychology, stringing it along such that it thinks that it's still in control of the situation and it is the one toying with the human, not the other way around.  Great skill will be required to apply enough alcohol to render the Plopup fully intoxicated without it realising that it is being trapped.

So much for gaining the upper hand in the situation; actually consummating the hunt requires the hunter to either kill the giant regenerating slimeball with their bare hands (which as the OP says seems impractical) or to "be inside it when it is killed".  The only way to kill a Plopup quickly and reliably seems to be high-temperature fire, like white phosphorus or thermite; the chemical preparation of white phosphorus is just about in reach of suitably clued-up fantasy alchemists.  As such, the full hunting process consists of:

1. The lure (cunning maiden) makes contact with the target Plopup and through cunning and guile establishes herself as *its* target
2. She reverse-traps the Plopup into an encounter at a suitable location
3. She manages to apply a large amount of alcoholic gel and get that absorbed by the Plopup, without alerting it
4. The Plopup becomes increasingly inebriated, to the point that it eventually agrees to the (highly irrational) idea of enveloping the cunning maiden whole *and unharmed*
5. As soon as the consumption is complete, the lure's accomplices (stereotypically burly men, although anyone who can lift a large pot will do) burst in and douse the Plopup with white phosphorus.
6. The lure hopes to hell that the Plopup dies before either a) she dies of asphyxiation or hyperthermia, or b) the Plopup kills her out of spite.  She'll then use the regenerative powers and speed of the Sevenfold Enchantment once she gains them to survive the rather tricky situation.

This doesn't actually require the lure to be particularly combat skilled, so it could be offered as a 'service' by a team of phosphorus-wielders.  Wouldn't be my preferred vocation, but there's something out there to suit everyone...!

Comment: Stephen, this is one of the best answers to this question right off the bat. One of the linked questions concerns this, and the lure would actually be healed _and_ enchanted when the Plopup dies. Also, Plopup already prefer to eat their maiden prey whole and unharmed, for sadistic reasons. They also have a certain level of arrogance, making tricking one into thinking it is the one in power is actually pretty feasible for a savvy maiden.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please know I would have accepted it as well if I could.

Answer (score 2):

#### They beat it to the brink of death with weapons, then someone stomps it to death.

Simply put, in order to benefit from the Sevenfold Enchantment, the killing blow needs to to delivered with the human body, but the previous blows don't seem to matter.

So, for a human to get the enchantment, a bunch of dudes with swords and axes (who might themselves possess the Sevenfold Enchantment) surround it and begin chopping bits off until its been weakened enough that they can throw a piece of waterproofed cloth over it and pin it to the ground.

Then the person who was chosen to get the power walks up, stands on top of the cloth, and starts stomping on it until it dies.

Comment: Good job; I myself didn't think of having armed helpers, your point is valid. However, it has some problems in that Plopup are _really_ tough, have a great healing factor, and a Plopup could rip or maybe even slip out of a tarp trap. Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: If you look at the previous question on Plopups and account for the information therein, I think this answer could be a real winner!