# Benefits of Boomerang Enchantment on Items

Tags: magic, items

Okay, so this question is in the same vein as [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195622/wingjaw-steel-superior-armor-and-weaponry) and [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/196057/benefits-of-amphibious-items) question (both posted by me). So, without further ado, what *is* the Boomerang Enchantment?

Simply put, items with the Boomerang Enchantment fly (accurately) in a loop when thrown, to the target and back to the owner, akin to an actual boomerang (yet not at the same time: boomerangs generally don't come back if they hit something). If the item is dropped, left behind, or taken away, it will return to the owner's hand in the same time it'd take a boomerang to return after being thrown the same distance.

(If you're confused, by "same distance" I mean the distance between the owner and the item; the item should return back to the owner's hand (*by teleporting*, since the item, in this case, has not been thrown and cannot change its current trajectory to return to its owner's hand) in thirty minutes max, but the time it takes for the owner to receive the said item is determined by how fast a thrown boomerang would return to the thrower if it was thrown the same distance and that time can therefore be longer than thirty minutes).

EDIT: To clarify, if an item with the Boomerang Enchantment is left behind or taken, it will teleport safely to the owner's hand. If it has been *thrown*, however, the thrower better be paying attention, or said item *can* and *will* hurt them upon return.

The only items that can hold this enchantment are organic or steel items (because steel contains carbon, which is generally organic in origin) and they must be used to kill a certain monster (Boomerang Bananas, very deadly, they fling themselves at *and through* people) in order to gain this enchantment. With that stipulation, my question is **How Beneficial Would Be The Boomerang Enchantment On Items?**

Criteria for Best Answer:

1. The best answer will start with a basic summary of how useful this Enchantment would be on items in general, specifically items that can be used to kill a sentient, flying, magical, and razor-sharp fruit. Since this criterion demands an idea of *how* Boomerang Bananas can be killed, let it be known that Boomerang Bananas can be: crushed, smothered, drowned, buried, sliced, incinerated, eaten (if peeled, which would require them to be held down), or broken, say, by a steel-coated baseball bat.
2. The best answer will cover where this enchantment would be most beneficial; ie. which items would be best benefited by this enchantment. By items I mean weapons, pieces of armor (you can kill a piece of fruit by bashing it with a breastplate, yes?), perhaps valuables like cloth (you *can* smother a Banana with cloth, it's just difficult) or money (kind of hard to see how you'd kill a Boomerang Banana with coins without significant difficulty...)
3. The best answer will cover #1 and #2 thoroughly.

*Clarification:*

1. Items that were dropped, taken, or left behind teleport back to the owner, *safely*; the time it takes them to return depends on how long it'd take a boomerang to return to the thrower after being thrown the same distance the item was dropped, taken to, or left behind at.

As always, I appreciate your input and feedback, you have my sincere thanks. I desire to post good questions on this site, so if you decide to VTC or close-vote, I am open to constructive criticism.

Comment: Would this item always safely return to the thrower's hand, or it may hurt the thrower in the process?

Comment: @Alexander: good point, let me edit that in. If it's teleporting in, it returns _safely_, but if it's been _thrown_, it can hurt the thrower upon flying back.

Comment: A scenario to consider - if someone drops an enchanted anvil on the enemy's head, and the enemy dodges it - would the anvil drop to the ground, line a non-enchated anvil, or fly back to hit the thrower?

Comment: Good question! I thought I had made this clear, but clearly I didn't; if an item is simply dropped, it will return within a certain period of time, determined by how fast a boomerang would return if thrown the same distance from the thrower. If it was _thrown down_, however, the thrower will likely be getting a Darwin Award presently.

Comment: The reall question... what happens wih humans?

Comment: @Writer-of-stories: good question, I'll post a question on that premise presently.

Answer (score 9):

## Infinite Energy AGAIN

Enchant a large bathtub with this (how do you use a bathtub to kill someone? Drown them, or use the bathtub kinetically).

Now dam some water and drop some of it on a watermill or turbine. Throw the bathtub in empty, call it back full. Rinse and repeat.

## Very fast messaging

Enchant paper (paper cuts to the throat can kill, you know). Send some to your pen pal. You can agree on a time and date when you will call each page back. This allows for a very fast mailing system, could even do for medieval internet.

Comment: Okay, this is ridiculous; I've broken the third law of thermodynamics THREE TIMES! The benefit to messaging would be good, though it would require some fine-tuning of the base enchantment....or perhaps Boomerang Ink would work? Very thought-provoking, thank you!

Comment: @Alendyias you can be cool with thermodynamics if you require the user to spend energy to make the magic work. They should need to spend more energy than what you get from using the magic.

Comment: Or, if you want cheese time, equal energy.

Answer (score 5):

**Surfboards**.  What can go wrong?  I mean, except for trying to find somebody to sell the thing to after it gets dark out.

**Spacecraft**.  They follow a ballistic trajectory until they hit the Moon or Mars, then they bring the sample back for free.

**Shipping boxes**.  Forget drones, the customer takes ownership of the shipping box.  For bulk items, as some damage may occur during transit.  Then he signs ownership back to the company, and away it goes!

**Poison**.  First you poison a helpless, unsuspecting banana.  Then you use the poisoned corpse of the banana to make a poisoned Savoy Truffle.  You bring it to your customer, and he becomes desperately ill.  But ... it is coming *back* again.  But you must be very careful to choose a well-heeled customer, because if his credit card is declined ... it will return to its owner.

**Bowling balls**.  If you're suffering a terrible terminal disease, don't forget to put in an online bid for one of these babies.  Being sure not to have forgotten your favorite politician in your will ... with instructions that it be executed only after the ball is thrown, right hard.

Comment: As funny as this is, it doesn't entirely make sense. Granted, Boomerang Packages would provide for _insane_ shipping speeds, or maybe not. How fast would boomerangs travel over miles?  See, why would you want a poisoned Truffle to come _back_ to you? And why would you put this enchantment on a Surfboard?

Comment: @Alendyias So you can say stick out your hand and yell out "To me, my board!" and use it to soar to the ends of the universe...and beyond!

Comment: @Alendyias didn't say anything about being able to give commands - these items seem to simply return to who owns them.  Provided the customer has successfully made a transaction, the poison would return to him after he ... throws it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Free money - You can make enchanted coins by beating the monster to death with a bag of money

You pay for something, ie "leave it with a merchant", and it returns to you 30 minutes later. You'll never have to pay for anything again.

#### You can kill anyone remotely by enchanting a grenade and gifting it to them.

Bad guy has bankrupted me. Removalists are coming to take all my possessions and the contract is sitting on my desk. I get a grenade, use it to smoosh a boomerang banana and it becomes a boomerang grenade. I then sign the contract, count 29 minutes and 25 seconds, and pull the pin out.

At the 30 minute mark, the grenade returns to its new owner (safely - so it just appears in their hand), and goes kaboom. Day saved.

You may need to seperate the pin from the grenade for the initial enchanting (so the pin doesn't come too). The grenades I'm familiar with have a cap that the pin holds in as the final safety, so if you're careful you can keep the cap on during the banana squishing.

Comment: Feed boomerang food to people.

Answer (score 1):

**Captain America**

Think about it. With such an enchantment, military purposes would no doubt follow. One of the easiest to achieve, and the coolest of course, would be boomerang shields. Just watch it in action!

Here is one example from [tenor.com.](https://tenor.com/view/captain-america-shield-chris-evans-steve-rogers-explosion-gif-4208089) [This compilation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C43cdTk0kao) also shows numerous uses, such a knocking out enemies from trees, keeping open closing doors, blocking bullets, and so on and so forth.

[image]

Comment: Tony does cast that enchantment on Cap's shield in Avengers: Age of Ultron.