# Can Anklebiters Become Living Stone?

Tags: magic

Wild Anklebiters are hybrid monsters; part tunneling leech, part flower. This hybrid nature grants them extra vitality, which is conferred to objects or creatures that kill them. This is called Vivification.

If a normal monster dies by natural causes, its magic goes haywire and creates [Drops](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/195344/preventing-dead-monsters-from-spawning-undead). These Drops are infused with monster essence. However, that extra vitality I mentioned earlier makes it so Anklebiters dead by natural cases enter a sort of stasis, much like a Hollywood zombie, instead of blowing apart or rotting away. And that extra essence is just sitting there, preserving the shell, just waiting to be absorbed by whatever absorbs the Anklebiter's remains.

**But what if they aren't absorbed?** Ever hear how fossils form? Or jet, a form of petrified wood? It usually involves sediment and water. If those remains, filled with lingering life essence, were to get petrified, the result would be stone with life in it. But-this would *only* happen if the stone was formed of or incorporated the Anklebiter's biological material. This leaves carbonation, perimineralization, or whatever the process of jet forming is called.

Better yet, this is somewhat *feasible*-leeches are aquatic, many plants can survive submerged at least temporarily, and Anklebiters live all over (their distribution is **rather like dandelions,** but they look more like tulips, just cone-shaped with pointy petals) so **they can be found in the right environments for these processes to take hold of their remains.**

(They're not found primarily in these environments, they're just abundant in general and can be found in these environments, if that helps.)

**Even then, here is my problem:** *I don't know enough about how fossilization works.* What kind of environment and conditions are required to A) preserve Anklebiter remains in sediment and B) see those same remains not only preserved but bound to minerals (to make a fossil) or metamorphosed into something like coal to make a stone.
This is especially problematic, because Anklebiters are basically worms stuck inside and fused with a herbaceous flower, and both worms and herbaceous flowers aren't known for becoming well-preserved.

**With that in mind,** my question is to determine if Anklebiters can realistically get fossilized in such a way as to create numerous deposits of living stone. Whether there's a shot of the fossils happening, and how likely it is, so I can determine if enough 'living rocks' could form to create a new species. That is my question.

**Please assume** that the time passed is sufficient for fossils or jet to have formed from Anklebiters if such a thing is possible; **this question assumes that it is *theoretically* possible, but is meant to determine if it is *realistically* possible.**

Finally, please note monster Drops or removed parts (think Monster Hunter) naturally contain some monster essence. Pluck a leaf from an Anklebiter, it'll hold a sliver of the full Vivification Enchantment. Thus, the husk left behind by an Anklebiter perishing, if infused with minerals (fossilized) or carbonated (turned into coal) will hold Vivification and be more or less alive. Once again, this is what I'm looking at, whether these living stones can be realistically created in large numbers.

**A Description of Anklebiters:**

To try and clear things up, Anklebiters are like protists, but evolved into a relatively large stage. In other words, they are much like herbaceous flowers, in form and also in cell biology (cell walls and chloroplasts) but also different in many ways. They possess setae and secrete mucus, they have ganglion at the center of their nervous network to help dictate decisions (much like an octopus), their petals and sepals are tough and flexible like tentacles, with the petals even possessing hard-to-see spines to aid in prey capture, and the center of the flower may resemble anthers or a stigma, but close inspection or dissection will reveal a surprisingly leechlike mouth.

They even reproduce much like flowers, producing unfertilized eggs within their bodies and then depositing them within the flower, where symbiotic bugs end up carrying them to other Anklebiters. However, instead of pollen, they produce toxic globules that are dispersed by the air to weaken and confuse prey so they can feed.

Comment: I'm unsure what you want from us. This is a fantastic setting. If you want new species of monsters there will be new species if monsters. If you don't there won't. As a worldbuilder of a fantastic setting, with as underdefined a magic system as you have, the result can be whatever you want it to be no more, no less. Don't waste you time seeking our approval, go and built your fantastic world. In the meantime I'm going to VTC this as POB. As has been explained to you many times before if the answer to a question depends on worldbuilder discretion it's not suitable for this site.

Comment: Putting aside the suitability of the question, I don't understand the process you are describing. Does the creature get turned into jet while still alive? Does the earth kill it, get its enchantment and then turn into stone. Why is that stone alive? And what does the resin have to do with everything else? Try and describe it in three or four sentences.

Comment: @Daron, I have tried to clarify for understanding. Please let me know how it works.

Comment: @Tortliena: I've edited, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @AngryMuppet: thank you, I have edited.

Comment: VTR... and I think a good answer could focus on biological remains inside fossils. How much material of the *actual animal* is preserved in a fossil ? Or is a fossil a piece of dead rock, with the Anklebiter shape stamped into it.. and its life essence being transferred into the surrounding sediment sand, or into the water, long before fossilisation starts..

Comment: Voting to reopen, the creature's description and behaviour on death is clear enough now, even more than what I expected :). I've deleted my old comments since they aren't really relevant anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Enchanted Microrganisms**

From what I understand, fossilization is when the empty spaces in a dead creature, get filled by minerals that then hardens. For example the cytoplasm in the cells gets replaced with silt that is later compressed into stone.

The organic material, for example the cell walls, either decomposes and washes away or just decomposes into simpler forms of carbon. In either case the creature does not remain in its original form.

In the former case (material gone) the enchantment gets swept away into the water and absorbed by the plankton that live there. You get enchanted plankton.

In the latter case  (material here but different) here's the thing -- organic material doesn't just *decompose*. It gets eaten by stuff. Small microscopic stuff. These tiny creepy crawlies ate the organic matter in the dead creature and pooed out simpler forms of carbon. By the rules of Alendyias I declare the enchantment passes to the microorganisms.

What happens to the microorganisms then? Well likely they eat everything nearby and then die and make loads of tiny drops. At this point I would dictate that tiny bacteria-sized drops can seep into inorganic matter given enough time and impart their enchantment.

Comment: Microbes leaving drops is a curious concept. That would imply that things like corral reefs would have magical properties based on which microorganisms are present. Or that washing your teeth would create lots of microscopic bits of junk.

Comment: @LiveInAmbeR Enchantments and microbes is something I would not touch myself. That way madness lies. I would just have a rule that the enchantments evaporate once they get spread out enough.